# Why are firstFew lines missing from the draft of WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have written html code in the WordPress. Without saving I just click on the preview button and the code works fine. Now,  save and close the draft. Now when I open the draft the first 5 lines of html code will be missing why it's that so.

below is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<div>

    <ul>
        <li><a
            href="#Menu1"
            target="_blank">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a
            href="#Menu2"
            target="_blank">Menu 2</a></li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

After SAving it as draft and reopening of the page I get the below code

```
&nbsp;
<div>

    <ul>
        <li><a
            href="#Menu1"
            target="_blank">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a
            href="#Menu2"
            target="_blank">Menu 2</a></li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

earlier this was not the case,Its happening from recent this code. Is there any major code im missing?

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress editor remove line-breaks, paragraphs and some other empty tags that it think is not important.

You can avoid this behavior by adding this code to the end of functions.php theme or child theme file:

```
// stop wp removing div tags
function tinymce_fix( $init )
{
    // html elements being stripped
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'div[*], article[*]';
    // don't remove line breaks
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
    // convert newline characters to BR
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true;
    // don't remove redundant BR
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;
    // pass back to wordpress
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_fix');
```

Comment: It is removing the html tag and head tag

Comment: Well you can't write HTML tag and head tag in WordPress editor, as each page should have one HTML and head tag and I believe those are already present on the page, coming from header.php

Comment: Im not having any .php... I just want to write a simple html code and want to execute it. this is the only page im having.